# Kotlin. ArrayList, how to move element to first position

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, arraylist, collections, data-class

I have a list of `Lessons`. Here is my `Lessons` class:

```
data class Lessons(
 val id: Long,
 val name: String,
 val time: Long,
 val key: String
)
```

I need to move the element to the beginning of the list, whose `key` field has a value "priority".
Here is my code:

```
   val priorityLesson = lessons.find { it.key == "priority" }
        
        if (priorityLesson != null) {
            lessons.remove(priorityLesson)
            lessons.add(0, priorityLesson)
        }
```

Everything is working but I do not like this solution, perhaps there is a more efficient way to perform this algorithm. In addition, it comes to me to convert the list to mutable, and I would like to leave it immutable.

Please help me.

Comment: Your list is obviously already mutable since you are calling `add` and `remove` on it.

Comment: because I am calling .toMutableList()

Comment: The use of fixed strings for the `priority` field has the feel of [stringly](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/stringly-typed-vs-strongly-typed)-[typed](https://cocoacasts.com/the-danger-of-string-literals-and-stringly-typed-code) [code](https://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped).

Comment: If you want to change the contents of your `lessons` property, you have two options - make the list it holds *mutable*, or keep the list immutable but make the property a `var`, so you can replace it with a modified copy of the list. If you're worried about performance, you could make `lessons` a `LinkedList` which allows you to remove and insert items without the cost of shifting items in an array. Computers are very fast at working with arrays though, and you're trading this benefit for a decrease in lookup/iteration speed. You should benchmark it to see if these differences are meaningful

Comment: Also you can always keep a list as a mutable type internally (`MutableList`, `LinkedList` etc) but expose it publicly as the immutable `List` type. That way you can make changes without creating new lists, but you get the benefit of immutability everywhere else

Answer (score 6):

One way is to call [`partition()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/partition.html) to split the list into a list of priority lesson(s), and a list of non-priority lessons; you can then rejoin them:

```
val sorted = lessons.partition{ it.key == "priority" }
                    .let{ it.first + it.second }
```

As well as handling the case of exactly one priority lesson, that will cope if there are none or several. And it preserves the order of priority lessons, and the order of non-priority lessons.

(That will take a little more memory than modifying the list in-place; but it scales the same — both are (n). It's also easier to understand and harder to get wrong!)

Answer (score 2):

First, I would call your class `Lesson` rather than `Lessons` as it represents a single lesson. Your choice of the variable name `lessons` is good for your list of lessons.

You can use a mutable list and move the item to the top:

```
val priorityLessonIndex = lessons.indexOf { it.key == "priority" }
if (priorityLessonIndex != -1)
    lessons[0] = lessons[priorityLessonIndex]
        .also { lessons[priorityLessonIndex] = lessons[0] }
```

Or you can use an immutable list:

```
val priorityLesson = lessons.firstOrNull { it.key == "priority" }
val newList =
    if (priorityLesson != null)
        listOf(priorityLesson) + (lessons - priorityLesson)
    else
        lessons
```

A possibly more efficient way, which avoids creation of intermediate lists:

```
val newList = buildList(lessons.size) {
    lessons.filterTo(this) { it.key == "priority" }
    lessons.filterTo(this) { it.key != "priority" }
}
```

Comment: thank your for answer, as far as I understand, in the first method you swap places, but I need to keep the order of the elements, and only move the priority element to the top. But can't problems arise if the array is very large when using the second method?

Comment: @testivanivan the second one creates a new (immutable) `List`, by combining your *priority* item with another list created by dropping the first instance of *priority* from the original list. You can look at the code for `minus` here: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/ea836fd46a1fef07d77c96f9d7e8d7807f793453/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Collections.kt#L3136 What kind of "problems" are you worried about?

Comment: @cactustictacs one possible problem is the creation of two temporary intermediate lists which are then copied to the result list and discarded. I've added an alternative solution at the end, which avoids creation of temporary lists and thus might perform a bit better.